# Edit printer preferences using printui.dll

Tags: windows, printer-properties

Can I use printui.dll to edit the printer preferences(Number of copies to be printed).

Currently am using this dll for viewing the properties using this syntax

"RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /e /n "myprinter" How should I change this to modify the settings like copies/paper size etc.

Note: Am attempting this to for an automation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use `SetPrinter.exe` from Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit.
You can find usage examples on the internet. In your case where you need to set number of copies, i think the commandline would be like (for 6 copies)

`SetPrinter "myprinter" 2 "pdevmode=dmCopies=6"`